# Bios не позволяет нажать enter для Exit & Save Changes

Tags: железо, bios

Добрый день товарищи. Помогите пожалуйста советом.
Есть материнская плата ABIT - AG8 c BIOS версии AwardBIOS 6.00PG от Phoenix.

Ситуация такая.
 При подключении заведомо рабочей клавиатуры, и нажатии DEL попадаем в биос.
Меняем настройки, все кнопки в том числе и ENTER работают. НО стоит нажать F10 для сохранения настроек кнопка Enter перестаёт работать. Вернее BIOS не реагирует на нажатие  и сохранить ничего не могу. Как быть?

Comment: Сброс настроек через перемычку и изъятие батарейки не помог.

Comment: Некоторые биосы поддерживают нажатие кнопки "Y" сокращение от YES

Comment: Я бы задумался о прошивке

Comment: @RuslanSemenov да нажимаем "Y" затем ENTER. Но ENTER не срабатывает

Comment: Если не дает так, то сохраните через F2. После перезагрузите.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov
 В данном биосе нету F2
http://www.probios.ru/picture/000076/0001.gif

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а второй enter проверяли ?

Comment: @RuslanSemenov проверял. не реагирует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, такого рода зависания не редкость.
Проблема решена небыла, но выяснилось, что при нажатии "y" для сохранения настроек, настройки всё таки сохранялись, но необходимо было перезагрузить компьютер "насильно", так как зависание BIOS не позволяло ему это сделать.